# How to gracefully close other program that do not have a main window?

Tags: c#

I want to close another program that does not have a main window.
It runs in background.

So `process.CloseMainWindow()` will not work, 
And using `process.kill()` will lose some data.

Is there a graceful way to close this kind of program without losing data for example by means of `SendMessage` or something else?

Comment: Ask it to close? Depends on the application there are different ways --> too broad.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason why your program is keeping the process alive. Check if you have made any refrences to objects that you should be done with by the time your program is about to exit

Comment: @user202729 can you mention some of them for example?

Comment: @S.Serp Send a signal?

Comment: Did you make the other program?  If it runs in the _"background"_ then it should be a Windows Service then shutting it down is simply by way of service control

Comment: @moonkop is it a windows service or a third party app? can you give more details about the program you want to close?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/959364/on-windows-how-can-i-gracefully-ask-a-running-program-to-terminate?

Comment: @Natan the superuser solution is good .And I can run taskkill in C# as a process. but is there something like taskkill without /f in c#?

Comment: @S.Serp my application to shutdown is ShadowsocksR.exe a http proxy program runs in background and leave a tray icon in the task bar.

Comment: @MickyD Yes ,I made this program and compile in c# ,Infact it's shadowsocksR indeed .It's just a small program puts a tray icon in task bar  not a windows service

Comment: You may try sending WM_QUIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/110413/1902354, but that also depends on how the app is implemented.  I'd look for a way to close the app using itself, some apps accept a `stop` command when you call it. See if it has any command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> It's just a small program puts a tray icon in task bar not a windows service

In that case it must have a message pump and so you can post a Windows `WM_QUIT` message to the process.  When the target process processes it message pump and encounters this message, it will gracefully quit.  Alternatively, you may post `WM_CLOSE` but then you need to know which window (it still works if the window is invisible).