# Is there a way to Start and Stop a Process Hidden via C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to Start a Custom App/Process (.exe) via C#. The App is written in python with pyQT5 the UI is hidden so the User sees it in den Systray on Windows. The app was compiled with pyinstaller.

I can start the app via C# that is not the problem but I do not find a way to close the app at the closing event of the C# app. I am wondering if this could ever work.

```
            // Open the app
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "my_app_bin\\";
            processStartInfo.FileName = "my_app.exe";
            //processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            //                processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            //                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //                processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            Process processTemp = Process.Start(processStartInfo);


           ....
           ....

           // closing the app
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("my_app");
        foreach (Process p in localByName)
        {
            //var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

            //ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE);
            //SetForegroundWindow(handle);

            p.CloseMainWindow();
            p.Close();
        }
    }
```

I also tried some other method over ShowWindow to first make it visible but nothing works. For a test i modified my python app to not going hidden - then it works so it depends on that. Then I tried Window Style Hidden in C# but the python app stays visible. Dose someone knows how I have to modify the pyqt5 app so that the

```
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

works?

I need a hidden Solution. It would be great if anyone has an Idea.

Thanks,
mathias

Comment: if you start the process, dont let the process go out of scope and you can do what you like with it later.

Comment: Did you try ShowWindow with the SW_Show flag? Because when its hidden you need to show it again? SW_Show has the integer value 5.

Comment: Yes I also tried ShowWindow. I also tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110336/closing-a-minimized-iconized-process-from-c-sharp but it does not work.